# UITableView scaled when dismiss from a UIWindow which only support landscape

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiwindow

When `UITableView` is clicked I want to display a `ViewController` that only supports landscape,If I use present method to display a `BViewController` from `AViewController`, when I return, `UITableView` on `AViewController` will reloadData due to rotation which is not what I want.

If I create a `UIWindow` which has a `rootViewController` that only supports `landscapeRight`. it works well but it has a bug.

1. click the cell and show the `UIWindow` with a `UIViewController` that only support landscape
2. click home button to exit the app
3. go back to the app
4. click the view to dismiss the UIWindow

then you will see `UITableView` has been scaled.

[bug image](http://lessimore.cn/Simulator%20Screen%20Shot%20-%20iPhone%2011%20-%202019-12-13%20at%2012.50.16.png)

[here is a demo](https://github.com/LeaderBoy/Landscape)

How to solve this bug about `UITableView` being scaled

Comment: Image url is dead

Comment: oh no,works now @Cerlin

Comment: which simulator or device are you checking it on it is working fine on iOS 8 simulator

Comment: @SouravSachdeva iOS12 and iOS13